# Python built-in fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to run a pytest which uses the following function:

```
def storage_class(request):

    def fin():
        sc.delete()

    request.addfinalizer(fin)

    logger.info("Creating storage")
    data = {'api_version': 'v1', 'kind': 'namespace'}
    # data is ususally loaded from yaml template
    sc = OCS(**data)
    return sc
```

I cannot find in the project any fixture named "request" so I assume it's a built-in fixture. I have however searched it in the docs, but I cannot find a "request" build-in fixture: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html
Anybody can shed some light on this (builtin?) fixture?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` fixture helps to get information about the context.

[more on request fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#request).

[Example for request fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#request-example).

The most common usage from request fixture is `addfinalizer` and `config`

And if you only need a `teardown` functionality, you can simply use a `yield` and get rid of the `request` fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def storage_class():

    logger.info("Creating storage")
    data = {'api_version': 'v1', 'kind': 'namespace'}
    sc = OCS(**data)
    yield sc

    # Any code after yield will give you teardown effect
    sc.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks you for the clarification!